# Overloaded/Overridden in Java

Tags: java, overriding, overloading

If I have

```
class A
{
 void foo(){}
 void foo(int a){}
}

class B extends A
{
 void foo(){}
}
```

Would the method **foo()** in **class A** be both overridden and overloaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It is both overloaded and overridden.

`foo` overloaded in classA with method `foo(int a)`

`foo` overridden in Class B with method `foo()`

Answer (score 2):

If you call `foo(){}` from a B object, then that method would be overridden.
If you call `foo(int a){}` from an A object, then that method would be overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

`A objA = new A();`
`objA.foo(10);` //(Overloading)

`A objAB = new B();`
`MobjAB.foo();`// (Overriding, Method of B will be called instead of A)